# Cordova - Issues when a cross platform android app is run on Blackberry 10 alpha simulator

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am facing problems in running a cross platform android App in blackberry 10 Alpha simulator.
The App works fine when run in iphone, android devices.
But when I run it in blackberry 10 it doesn't load the template files hence a blank screen.

The project is based on backbone framework hence template files. 
Currently the files are local in my hard-disk. I am loading the templates using an ajax call.
The logcat output generated of the same is listed below:

```
02-08 05:30:51.861: D/CordovaLog(233525377):
     {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

I have added the following to config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"></access>
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

Is there anything else I am missing to make the app run on blackberry 10??
I had the same issue with nook HD which was avoided by adding the following to `onCreate`:

```
super.appView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

But since blackberry uses 2.3.3 of Android, I am unable to add the same settings.

Please let me know If I am missing any specific configuration related content for blackberry 10.

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using ? My first thought would be to check out [the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/index.html) of your version and checkout the platform ***squirks***